# Find majority number in an array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

This question has been asked before. However I just want to know what is wrong with my code. It passes most of the test cases but not all of them on lintcode.

Given an array of integers, the majority number is the number that occurs more than half of the size of the array. Find it.

```
public class Solution {
    /**
     * @param nums: a list of integers
     * @return: find a  majority number
     */
    public int majorityNumber(ArrayList<Integer> nums) {
        // write your code
        Collections.sort(nums);
        int j = 0, count = 0, out = 0, size = nums.size();

        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if(nums.get(j) == nums.get(i)) {
                count++;
                if(count > size/2){
                    out = nums.get(i);
                }
            } else {
                count = 1;
                j = i;
            }
        }
        return out;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I changed the code to j = i & count = 1 as suggested by an answer.

For example for the input [1,1,1,2,2,2,2] the output should be 2. 
My code works in this case. It doesn't work in large input cases.

I don't want another solution, as I have already found many O(n) solutions on other sites. I just want to fix my own code and know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What language is this? Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @EdCottrell It's java

Comment: Please add more information. You say it doesn't pass some test cases. Which ones? Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What is this line intended for?  `j++;i--;`

Comment: An issue I can see right away is when i = j = 0 you count "for nothing"

Comment: Your treatment of `i` and `j` looks strange. Walk through your algorithm with a small example and keep track of your indices `i` and `j`.

Comment: What case doesn't work? The alg seems right for me

Comment: @JohnnyWiller in very large test cases

Comment: @SadiqHusainKhan probably there is no number that appears more than the half of the size. Can you show an example of large test case? How have you made the test?

Comment: @JohnnyWiller No, I haven't made any case. lintcode has it's own test cases, and in one of those test cases it fails. It also shows that there is a majority number in that test case

Answer (score 3):

There's a smart solution that runs in O(n) worst case time, and no additional space:

```
  public static int majorityNumber(List<Integer> nums) {
    int candidate = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for (int num : nums) {
      if (count == 0)
        candidate = num;
      if (num == candidate)
        count++;
      else
        count--;
    }
    return candidate;
  }
```

Note that it assumes the existence of a majority value, otherwise it returns an arbitrary value.

Answer (score 0):

Debug your code and print the values of `i` and `j`. I'm sure that will not be what you wanted to do.

You wanted to read each element and count it's frequency. That would be a `O(n*n)`(because the array is sorted `O(n log(n))`) solution.

```
ArrayList<Integer> readNums = new ArrayList();
for(int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
{
  int currentNum = a[i];
  if(list.contains(currentNum)
    continue;//to check if you already processed that num
  else 
    list.add(currentNum);
  int count = 0;
  for(int j = i + 1; j < a.length; ++j)
  {
    if(currentNum == a[j])
      count ++;
   }
   if(count > size / 2)
    reqNum = currentNum;
}
```

This is what you wanted to do.

---

A better method would be to use a space of O(n) and track the frequencies and then process the array in O(n).

```
HashMap<Integer, Intege> map = new HashMap();

for(int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
{
  int currentNum = a[i];
  int count = 1;
  if(map.containsKey(currentNum))
  {
    count = map.getValue(currentNum);
    map.put(currentNum, count + 1);
    count ++;
  }
  else
  {
    map.put(currentNum, count);
  }
  if(count > size / 2)
    reqNum = currentNum;
}
```

Comment: OP's solution is O(N·log(N)), because the array is sorted first, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

In your else block do:

```
...
else {
    count = 1;
    j = i;
}
```

Comment: yes, you are right. That was what I wanted to do. Although it still hasn't solved my problem.